# How to change the button background color on mouse over using Trigger

Tags: silverlight

I trying to write simple code that contain button that will change the background color on mouse over.

I want to do it using Triggers - so i write this code - but i dont know how to continue

```
  <Button Background="#fafafa" >
        <Button.Triggers>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter"/> 

                  // What to do here to having thi background color change ?                     

        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to change Buttons template. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387013/how-remove-border-from-clicked-button-in-silverlight) post describes how to do that. In buttons template under **VisualStateManager** you will find `vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"` . Change its content as you need.

Or if you want do that with triggers, than take a loot to [Behaviors and Triggers in Silverlight](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Behaviors-and-Triggers-in-Silverlight-3.aspx) post on [silverlightshow.net](http://www.silverlightshow.net).